# Formatting a table that is plotted from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to publish a figure of a table that has been created from a dataframe for use in a report.

```
#Hard Coding example
TopTenSites = 238
RestOfSites = 387
#Creating a dataframe to pass into 
Proportion = pd.DataFrame({'Incidence': [TopTenSites, RestOfSites]},
             index=['Top 10 Sites', 'Rest of Sites'])

#Creating the table
fig, plot = plt.subplots(figsize = [3,2])
#plot.axis('off')
#Remove axis
plot.xaxis.set_visible(False) 
plot.yaxis.set_visible(False) 
#Creating the table
plot.table(cellText = Proportion.values, rowLabels = Proportion.index, loc = 'center', colLabels = 
Proportion.columns,cellLoc = 'center')
plt.savefig('Proportion.png')enter code here
```

The output in Jupyter notebook gives a table which looks like.

[image]

But the actual png produced by this code looks like

[image]

Does anyone know the formatting for a table so I can produce a png file that looks exactly like the
output where the row labels are included.

Comment: Can you include a minimum reproducible example? I am not able to replicate with my version of matplotlib. My output looks different.

Comment: I have re-edited the original question to include the dataframe used to create the pie chart.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was to recreate the dataframe with a default numerical index

```
#Creating a dataframe to pass into 
Proportion = pd.DataFrame({'Sites': ['Top 10 Sites', 'Rest of Sites'],'Incidence': 
[TopTenSites, RestOfSites]})

#Creating the table plot
fig, plot = plt.subplots(figsize = [3,2])
plot.axis('off')
#Remove axis
plot.xaxis.set_visible(False) 
plot.yaxis.set_visible(False) 
#Creating the table
plot.table(cellText = Proportion.values,loc = 'center', colLabels = 
Proportion.columns, cellLoc = 'center')
plt.savefig('Proportion.png')
```